# How to change a focused JButton's default keybinding for ActionListener?

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings, keystroke

The default key for calling a focused JButton's ActionListener is Space, but how do I change it to another key?

Comment: Please see edits to answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to:

1. Update the `InputMap` of the component to add new `KeyStroke` to point to the existing `Action`.
2. Prevent the existing `KeyStroke` in the `InputMap` from invoking the existing `Action`. This step is optional if you want to be able to use both KeyStrokes to invoke the default Action.

Note:

1. you need to update the `InputMap` for the "pressed" and "released" keys
2. updates to the `InputMap` must be done in the above order.

Modifying the code from Hovercrafts example you could do:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AlterSpaceBinding extends JPanel {
    private JButton myButton = new JButton("My Button -- associate with \"B\" key");

    public AlterSpaceBinding() {
        myButton = alterDefaultButtonAction(myButton, KeyEvent.VK_B);
        myButton.addActionListener(l -> {
            System.out.println("button pressed");
        });
        add(myButton);
        add(new JButton("Second Button -- no change"));

    }

    public static JButton alterDefaultButtonAction(JButton button, int desiredKeyCode) {

        // get the correct InputMap
        InputMap inputMap = button.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);

        // get both key strokes for space key, but pressed and released
        KeyStroke spaceKeyPressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0, false);
        KeyStroke spaceKeyReleased = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0, true);

        // key stroke for desired key code
        KeyStroke desiredKeyPressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(desiredKeyCode, 0, false);
        KeyStroke desiredKeyReleased = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(desiredKeyCode, 0, true);

        // share the Action with desired KeyStroke
        inputMap.put(desiredKeyPressed, inputMap.get(spaceKeyPressed));
        inputMap.put(desiredKeyReleased, inputMap.get(spaceKeyReleased));

        // disable original KeyStrokes (optional)
        inputMap.put(spaceKeyPressed, "none");
        inputMap.put(spaceKeyReleased, "none");

        return button;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        AlterSpaceBinding mainPanel = new AlterSpaceBinding();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("AlterSpaceBinding");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

The above code does not need to:

1. create a dummy `Action`.
2. manipulate the `ActionMap`.

Check out [Using Key Bindings](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for more examples of manipulating the `InputMap` and `ActionMap` of a component.

Note:

A more likely scenario is that you want to update the bindings for all the buttons in the application so you have a common LAF. In this case you can update the "focusInputMap" from the UIManager which is shared by all JButtons:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SSCCE extends JPanel
{
    SSCCE()
    {
        add( new JButton("Button 1" ) );
        add( new JButton("Button 2" ) );
        add( new JButton("Button 3" ) );
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new SSCCE());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );

        // Update shared InputMap

        InputMap inputMap = (InputMap)UIManager.get("Button.focusInputMap");
        int desiredKeyCode = KeyEvent.VK_B; // type "b" to invoke Action on button

        KeyStroke spaceKeyPressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0, false);
        KeyStroke spaceKeyReleased = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0, true);

        // key stroke for desired key code
        KeyStroke desiredKeyPressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(desiredKeyCode, 0, false);
        KeyStroke desiredKeyReleased = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(desiredKeyCode, 0, true);

        // share the Action with desired KeyStroke
        inputMap.put(desiredKeyPressed, inputMap.get(spaceKeyPressed));
        inputMap.put(desiredKeyReleased, inputMap.get(spaceKeyReleased));

        // optionally disable original KeyStrokes
        inputMap.put(spaceKeyPressed, "none");
        inputMap.put(spaceKeyReleased, "none");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not fully simple and requires:

- Using the correct InputMap for the JButton, the one associated with the `JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED` condition
- Then you need to obtain and remove InputMap and ActionMap for the button associated with the space key, for ***both** the key press ***and*** the key released.
- Then associate both actions with your key of interest, again *both* key pressed and released.

example:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AlterSpaceBinding extends JPanel {
    private JButton myButton = new JButton("My Button -- associate with \"B\" key");

    public AlterSpaceBinding() {
        myButton = alterDefaultButtonAction(myButton, KeyEvent.VK_B);
        myButton.addActionListener(l -> {
            System.out.println("button pressed");
        });
        add(myButton);
        add(new JButton("Second Button -- no change"));

    }

    public static JButton alterDefaultButtonAction(JButton button, int desiredKeyCode) {

        // get the correct InputMap
        int condition = JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED;
        InputMap inputMap = button.getInputMap(condition);
        ActionMap actionMap = button.getActionMap();

        // empty action that does nothing
        Action emptyAction = new AbstractAction() {            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // This does NOTHING
            }
        };

        // get both key strokes for space key, but pressed and released
        KeyStroke spaceKeyPressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0, false);
        KeyStroke spaceKeyReleased = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0, true);

        // get input map key for pressed and released
        String keyForSpacePressed = (String) inputMap.get(spaceKeyPressed);
        String keyForSpaceReleased = (String) inputMap.get(spaceKeyReleased);

        // get actions for press and release
        Action actionForSpacePressed = actionMap.get(keyForSpacePressed);        
        Action actionForSpaceReleased = actionMap.get(keyForSpaceReleased);

        // substitute empty action
        actionMap.put(keyForSpacePressed, emptyAction);
        actionMap.put(keyForSpaceReleased, emptyAction);

        // key stroke for desired key code
        KeyStroke desiredKeyPressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(desiredKeyCode, 0, false);
        KeyStroke desiredKeyReleased = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(desiredKeyCode, 0, true);

        // put in the original actions to where wanted
        inputMap.put(desiredKeyPressed, desiredKeyPressed.toString());
        actionMap.put(desiredKeyPressed.toString(), actionForSpacePressed);
        inputMap.put(desiredKeyReleased, desiredKeyReleased.toString());
        actionMap.put(desiredKeyReleased.toString(), actionForSpaceReleased);

        return button;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        AlterSpaceBinding mainPanel = new AlterSpaceBinding();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("AlterSpaceBinding");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: The ActionMap doesn't need to be changed: The OP just want to change the keystroke. @camickr's answer is the correct one.